# How to improve this code to obtain more compact equation?

Tags: math-mode, formatting

I have been trying to obtain more compact output for the following code. Any help will really be appreciated!

```
\Pr(s_i^2)=   F^{ij}_{i}\left[\displaystyle\frac{F^{i}_{j}\left[(F_j^{iji})^{-1}\left(\displaystyle\frac{ \varepsilon \left(F^{ij}_{i}\right)^{-1}\displaystyle\left(\frac{\varepsilon z_i^j+v_j^1}{v_j^1-v_j^2}\right)+v_{i}    }{ v_{i}^{1}-v_{i}^{2}   } \right)\right](v_i^1-v_i^2)-v_{i}^{1} }{\varepsilon} \right]
```

Comment: Without knowing the meaning of the symbols, it's difficult to help. Is `F^{ij}_{i}` simply a multiplier?

Comment: Using superscripted numbers like `v_i^2` is really unfortunate, are those supposed to be exponents or a label ? It's rather unclear

Comment: @egreg: It is a cumulative distribution function.

Comment: @ach: They are labelling different payoffs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should try and find another way to express the relations involved in the equation, perhaps by introducing names for intermediate expressions.

If that is not possible, then I suggest you try to remove as many of the big fractions as much as you can.

Also, assuming that there is no semantic difference between round brackets `(...)` and square brackets `[...]`, then it would be better to alternate them, increasing sizes after each pair to help lead the eye, and keeping the inner brackets as small as possible.  This is best acheived using commands such as `\bigl(...\bigr)` instead of `\left(...\right)`:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{displaymath}
  \Pr(s_i^2)=
  F^{ij}_i
  \biggr(
    \frac{v_i^1-v_i^2}\varepsilon
    F^i_j
    \biggl[
      {(F_j^{iji})}^{-1}
      \biggl(
        \frac1{v_i^1-v_i^2} \cdot
        \Bigl[
          \varepsilon {(F^{ij}_i)}^{-1}
          \Bigl(
            \frac{\varepsilon z_i^j+v_j^1}{v_j^1-v_j^2}
          \Bigr)
          + v_i
        \Bigr]
      \biggr)
    \biggr]
    \;-\; \frac{v_i^1}{\varepsilon}
  \Biggr)
\end{displaymath}

\end{document}
```

Here I have avoided big fractions by writing factors in front as `1/x` and if necessary distributing them as `a/x + b/x` in order to avoid even more brackets.  At the outer level I have added more space around the minus sign, to try to help with the grouping.  For the inverse functions I have written `(F)` with normal size brackets and then grouped this with `{...}^{-1}` to raise the inverse sign.  I have placed a `\cdot` at the inner level to indicate multiplication; this could also be used at the outer level if desired.

In older books on typography, one suggestion is to use three types of brackets `(...)`, `[...]`, `\{...\}`.  This way you can get three levels of nesting before having to increase the size.  However, in most modern texts we tend to associate `\{...\}` strongly with set specifications, so this is often not appropriate.  That said, it might be usable in your situation:

[image: Sample with curly brackets]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{displaymath}
  \Pr(s_i^2)=
  F^{ij}_i
  \biggr[
    \frac{v_i^1-v_i^2}\varepsilon
    F^i_j
    \biggl(
      {(F_j^{iji})}^{-1}
      \Bigl\{
        \frac1{v_i^1-v_i^2} \cdot
        \Bigl[
          \varepsilon {(F^{ij}_i)}^{-1}
          \Bigl(
            \frac{\varepsilon z_i^j+v_j^1}{v_j^1-v_j^2}
          \Bigr)
          + v_i
        \Bigr]
      \Bigr\}
    \biggr)
    \;-\; \frac{v_i^1}{\varepsilon}
  \biggr]
\end{displaymath}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Please compare:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\[
\Pr(s_i^2)=   
F^{ij}_{i}\left[\displaystyle\frac{F^{i}_{j}\left[(F_j^{iji})^{-1}\left(\displaystyle\frac{ \varepsilon \left(F^{ij}_{i}\right)^{-1}\displaystyle\left(\frac{\varepsilon z_i^j+v_j^1}{v_j^1-v_j^2}\right)+v_{i}    }{ v_{i}^{1}-v_{i}^{2}   } \right)\right](v_i^1-v_i^2)-v_{i}^{1} }{\varepsilon} \right]
\]

\[
\Pr(s_i^2)=   
F^{ij}_{i}\left[
\frac1\varepsilon\left[
\displaystyle{F^{i}_{j}\left[(F_j^{iji})^{-1}\left(\displaystyle\frac{ \varepsilon \left(F^{ij}_{i}\right)^{-1}\displaystyle\left(\frac{\varepsilon z_i^j+v_j^1}{v_j^1-v_j^2}\right)+v_{i}    }{ v_{i}^{1}-v_{i}^{2}   } \right)\right](v_i^1-v_i^2)-v_{i}^{1} } \right]\right]
\]

or even

\[
\Pr(s_i^2)=   
F^{ij}_{i}\left[
\frac1\varepsilon\left[
\displaystyle{F^{i}_{j}\left[
(F_j^{iji})^{-1}\left(
\displaystyle\frac1{v_j^1-v_j^2}
\left(
{ \varepsilon
 \left(F^{ij}_{i}\right)^{-1}\displaystyle\left(
\frac{\varepsilon z_i^j+v_j^1}{v_j^1-v_j^2}
\right)+v_{i}    }\right)
\right)
\right](v_i^1-v_i^2)-v_{i}^{1} } \right]
\right]
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

(Of course, if `compact` means here `not too high`).

Comment: Comment on the text of the question, not this answer nor the `TeX`: I suspect that any compact way to write this equation will make it unreadable. Why must it be compact? Can you separate out, name and explain some of the ingredients, then combine them? If I were your reader I would want that.

Comment: the `\frac{1}{\varepsilon}` needs to be moved outside the outermost brackets in the second example.  perhaps inserting a `\cdot` between `F^{ij}_i` and the fraction would help keep the intent clear.  alternatively, after the `=`, combining them as `\frac{F^{ij}_i}{\varepsilon}` might do the job.

Comment: @barbarabeeton But it is probably non-linear function.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke -- you're almost certainly right.  however, the problem i have is that i can't reconstruct the first equation from the second; the final `-v_{i}^{1}` has lost its connection with the `\varepsilon` in the denominator.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Oh, I see! Corrected. Tahnk you!